# The letters is written inversed in pdf by reportlab library when importing data from database table in arabic

Tags: python, sqlite, reportlab

I'm trying to import data in arabic from database and display it into table, using reportlab library but the output appears as separate and inversed letters[image]
this is a part of my code:

```
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
import sqlite3
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, inch
from reportlab.platypus import Image, Paragraph, SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont

def onFirstPage(canvas, document):
    arabic_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(u'بيان')
    arabic_text = get_display(arabic_text)
    pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Arabic-bold', 'tradbdo.ttf'))

    canvas.setFont('Arabic-bold', 14)
    canvas.drawString(50, 750,arabic_text)
    canvas.line(50, 740, 75, 740)

doc = SimpleDocTemplate("Report.pdf", pagesize=letter)
elements = []

styleSheet = getSampleStyleSheet()

P0 = Paragraph('''
A paragraph
1''',
styleSheet["BodyText"])
P = Paragraph(''' The ReportLab Left
Logo
Image''',
styleSheet["BodyText"])
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Arabic-bold', 'tradbdo.ttf'))
data = []
conn = sqlite3.connect("S:\الموارد البشرية & الرعاية الطبية\HR1.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT number, name, date1, date2 FROM agazat2')
for row in c.fetchall():
    data.append(row)
conn.close()
c_width=[0.5*inch,3*inch,1.5*inch,1.5*inch]
t=Table(data, rowHeights=20,repeatRows=1,colWidths=c_width, style=[('GRID',(0,0),(-1,-1),1,colors.black),
])
t.setStyle(TableStyle([
    ('FONTNAME', (0, 0), (-1, -1), "Arabic-bold"),
]))

elements.append(t)
doc.build(elements, onFirstPage=onFirstPage)
```

I tried a lot to solve this problem but I couldn't find a solution

Answer (score 0):

you have to use Arabic-reshaper + python-bidi packages to fix this. See here for more details: https://abderrahmane.hashnode.dev/how-to-add-arabic-text-on-pdf-with-reportlab